# Código confuso - qual o significado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap

Quando eu tenho esse código:

```
{{ 'js/gourmet.js' | static_url | script_tag }}
```

- O que significa?
- Onde eu acho esse `static_url ou o script_tag` ?
- Isso é jQuery?

Comment: provavelmente `static_url` e o `script_tag` sao variaveis... mas com apenas essa linha de codigo vai ser dificil alguem conseguir te ajudar.

Comment: Isso seria Angular?

Answer (score 1):

Isso se parece com uma linguagem de templates. Pode ser `Handlebars`.

Basicamente as chaves duplas dizem para o interpretador que aquilo é uma tag e que precisa ser substituída por um conteúdo HTML válido.

Ali no caso ele provavelmente importa uma tag de script com aquela URL.

O que vem depois dos `pipes` (barrinha "|") são filtros aplicados ao conteúdo. Então ele tem o conteúdo `js/gourmet` que passa pelo filtro `static_url` que provavelmente coloca o restante da URL já que é um arquivo estático e depois o filtro `script_tag` que provavelmente encapsula aquela URL numa tag script.

No final das contas ele deve substituir por:

```
 <script src="http://site.com/assets/js/gourmet.js" />
```

No primeiro filtro ele troca `js/gourmet` pelo `path` estático do arquivo e no segundo adiciona a tag de `script`.

Existem diversas linguagens de templates com diversos padrões. Esse padrão das chaves duplas veio com o `Handlerbars` e foi sendo adaptado por diversos frameworks como o `Angular` por exemplo.